# How to recognise all figure commands as figure*

Tags: floats, environments

I have a long tex file with many "figure" commands inside.

I included this source tex file in my main document. In the beginning of my file I am trying to renew the command figure as figure* but it does not work.

```
 \renewenvironment{figure}%
 {\begin{figure*}}
 {\end{figure*}}
```

Basically, whenever the document sees a figure, it should use figure*
Unfortunately I cannot modify the main source file (no find+replace).

The reason is I am using a shared content for multiple documents. These documents have different column layouts, so in one of the document I am trying to make it wider. If there is an alternative solution for multiple documents using same source files, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code will make all `figure` be interpreted as `figure*` and span two columns, this document produces

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\renewenvironment{figure}%
 {\begin{figure*}}
 {\end{figure*}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  abc
  \caption{zzzz}
  \label{fig:zz}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```